When two neutral atoms collide, and one atom ionizes, how does the speed of the ejected electron compare to that of the atoms?
When two neutral atoms collide, and one atom ionizes, how does the speed of the ejected electron compare to that of the atoms?
Context is, I was trying to do the calculations for the velocity of the resulting ion, free electron, and the projectile atom, after collision, using conservation of momentum and energy, and realized the equations are under-specified:

we have a single equation for energy, which is a scalar
let's assume two axes. So, then we have two equations for momentum: one for each axis

But, in 2d, we have 6 unknown scalars: two for each particle, one per axis.
So.... then I need to hunt around for some other approximations and empirical results.
Now, to simplify things note that we can always move our reference frame such that the two neutral atoms are always moving at equal and opposite velocities, though not necessarily aimed dead center at each other.
Then, checking with chatgpt, it appears that the electron can be ejected at basically arbitrarily angles, but the most probable angle is along the direction of the projectile atom. Let's say we have two atoms. Let's call one the 'ionized' atom, and the other the 'projectile' atom. The electron will tend to be ejected in the same direction that the projectile atom was moving before impact. Though at lower energies, the direction becomes more and more diverse.
Then, imagining a simple elastic collision of an electron-dimensionted billiard ball with an atom-sized billiard ball, it seems like the electron would move at 3 times the original speed of each of the neutral atoms? But is this a reasonable ok-ish approximation to what will happen? Or, will the electron tend to be moving much faster or slower than this?
Update, based on some of these comments:
So, in this question, I'm describing these particles as simple point masses. In reality, they are little balls of intersecting orbitals, which can exhibit some characteristics of elastic billiard balls, but clearly ionization itself is an exception to such a characteristic, but not the only one. According to where the particles strike each other, the resulting angles will vary.
That said, my understanding from chatgpt is that empirical evidence, at least at high energies, suggests that the electron will be ejected approximately along the line of the projectile atom (ie the atom knocking the electron out). Since the electron's mass is rather small, I'm going to assume that the remaining ion and atom behave approximately like elastic billiard balls, once the kinetic energy given to the electron has been removed, along with the ionization energy (i.e.  the electron and the ion drag each other towards each other, as the electron moves away, slowing both of them down, and removing kinetic energy from each).
So, I'm pondering approximating the collision of the projectile atom with the electron as an elastic head-on collision, which would imply that the electron moves away at three times the speed of the projectile atom (I think?). But I'm wondering how reasonable an approximation this is.
Update2: it looks like when a small mass escapes from the gravitational field of a large mass, the gravitational field reduces the kinetic energy of the smaller mass considerably more than that of he large mass? By the ratio of their masses. Here we have coulomb force rather than gravitational force, but the same equations apply. So, perhaps I should remove the ionization energy from the electron, following the elastic collision described above, between the projectile atom and the electron, as a reasonable-ish approximation?

In a reference frame such that the two neutral atoms are always moving at equal and opposite velocities, which atom is the projectile atom? The atoms are identical, and we don't know which of them emits the electron.

though not necessarily aimed dead center at each other for two atoms one can always choose a reference frame, where they move towards each other along a line - am I wrong?

@RogerV. - you can't always have them move toward each other along a line, in fact most of the time the center of masses are not moving directly at each other. You have an impact factor to consider. But, in general, for a 3-body problem there is no specific answer of what energy any given body will end up with.

@RogerV it's hard to intuit for balls, but imagine two cars, driving towards each other, on opposite sides of a road only wide enough for 1.9 cars. They will strike each other, at equal and opposite velocities, but only the edges of the cars will hit. The rest of each car will then pivot around that (stationary) point of impact. That is, there will be a rotational torque. Now, there is no linearly moving frame of reference in which the cars collide head-on, rather than having their edges impact. And there is no linearly moving frame of reference in which they don't rotate around that point.

Having convinced yourself with cars, you can now consider billiard balls. Most billiard ball collisions involve the two balls diverging at 90 degrees, relative to our static frame of reference, and both balls are moving at some angle relative to the initial direction of the cue ball, that is not 90degrees or 45 degrees. There is no linearly moving frame of reference in which the balls strike each other head-on, at equal and opposite velocities, and then rebound along that line. Such a frame of reference would have to be moving along the line of the initial cue ball.

@JonCuster presumably there is some kind of probaiblitiy distribution though over the possible directions and energies?

There's a component of velocity perpendicular to the line connecting cars, and the one along this line. The former one simply describes the displacement of the center of mass. Also, the description in the Q. ignores the inner structure of atoms - they are considered point-like. In your example of cars you consider them as rigid bodies - including rotation degrees of freedom, it is a different problem.

added an update to the question to describe the fact that atoms are not point masses.

The reasoning that I described is still valid for the center-of-mass. But now you need to add the angular momentum conservation. I suggest that you start writing equations - as is the discussion is meaningless.

ChatGPT now replaces university. For any questions left you can always go to PSE.

Yeah, ChatGPT is awesome. I am also dabbling in using physics stackexchange, but ChatGPT gives me answers faster, much of the time, with a few exceptions.

Oh, PSE is physics stack exchange. Yeah, right, exactly, though mostly I've just been answering my own questions...

Angular momentum conservation. Hmmm, interesting point.
